# How can I update the transactions status when cache expire?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

```
var cacheExpirationOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions 
{
    AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5),
    Priority = CacheItemPriority.Normal,
};
_memoryCache.Set(fakeTransactionId, transaction.Id,
    cacheExpirationOptions.RegisterPostEvictionCallback((key, value, reason, state) = > {
        TransactionStatusUpdate(transaction.Id, TransactionStatusType.UrlExpired);
    }));
```

I want to update the process when the default process expires, what should I do?

Comment: Unfortunately your question is not really understandable, cause we don't know what you mean by `process` in your question. Also what is your expectation to happen under which circumstances? How does your `process` interact with the memory cache? Please try to better explain what and how you insert something into the cache and what should happen in which cases.

Comment: @Oliver ı think doesnt matter process mean, cache time 'll be 5 minute and ı want to when time finishes starting automatic TransactionUpdate

Comment: Unfortunately the cache works a little different. The check if an entry is evicted and must be deleted (and thous executing the callback) will only be done whenever a request to the cache is made. So if you really need an exact timing, the memory cache is not the right class to use for. Instead you need something like `System.Timers.Timer` or build something with a `WaitHandle` and a maximum waiting time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        var expirationTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30);
        var expirationToken = new CancellationChangeToken(
            new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(31)).Token);

        var cacheEntryOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions()
         .SetPriority(CacheItemPriority.NeverRemove)
         .SetAbsoluteExpiration(expirationTime)
         .AddExpirationToken(expirationToken)
         .RegisterPostEvictionCallback(callback: EvictionCallback, state: this);
        _memoryCache.Set(fakeTransactionId, transaction.Id, cacheEntryOptions);
```

I found, when expirationTime finish EvictionCallback triggering.